# Trying to use Pi as a Router - dnsmasq reports interface eth1 does not currently exist

Tags: usb, dhcp

I am trying to use my Pi as a router and I want to start with getting DHCP set up.

I bought the Apple USB to ethernet adaptor and it seems to work fine.

The WAN is setup to eth0 - the built in ethernet on the pi board - while the connection to, say my laptop (the LAN) is on eth1.

eth1 indeed does seem to exist.

From ifconfig:

> eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:95:c2:5e
>             inet addr:10.0.1.7  Bcast:10.0.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:1252 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:625 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>             RX bytes:505779 (493.9 KiB)  TX bytes:64516 (63.0 KiB)
>
> eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:49:71:10:18:8b
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:764 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>             RX bytes:196172 (191.5 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

What am I doing wrong here? eth1 seems to be existing fine.

Comment: Here is a nice guide for [setting up the Pi as a router](http://qcktech.blogspot.de/2012/08/raspberry-pi-as-router.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your eth1 interface does not seem to have an IP Address.

You can assign an IP using the ifconfig command:

```
ifconfig eth1 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

The above command will assign an IP of 10.0.0.1 to the eth1 interface.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

dnsmasq can only use up and running network interfaces with assigned ip adress that corresponds to at least one configuration in your dnsmasq.conf (if you do not intend to use dnsmasq as dhcp server, it might work out)